# Where do websites like expertflyer.com get their information?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations, software, online-tracking

I've been looking at internet resources like expertflyer.com and KVSTool which query information like live seat maps, upgrade availability and fare bucket information. To my knowledge, this seemed like proprietary information unique to each individual airline. Is there a public API or database that these pieces of software are using or do they simply scrape the websites of each individual airline? Perhaps this might be a question better suited for Programming SE but I thought I'd start here.

Comment: The Open Data stack exchange site may have inputs here, since they tend to share info on what sources of data are available to the public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, ExpertFlyer gets its data from purchasing it from the GDSs (global distribution systems for airlines) these are the same systems that travel agents (online and off) use to book tickets/travel for their customers. This has a cost but has advantages vs free but less reliable means of acquiring flight data.

Other services may screen scrape (take) information from public airline websites, however airlines frown upon that. We have seen active campaigns by airlines to go after services that collect data in this manor.

Please note, this post is not meant to be "promotional" however fully answering the question posed requires explaining how different services may acquire flight data. Also, if the name "ExpertFlyer Voice" didn't indicate to you, I am a representative of ExpertFlyer.com

Comment: Although the factual answer is in here, there's quite some promotionial content around it. As such, it might be flagged as spam and removed, please clean up your answer to include factual information only.

Comment: I don't see the promotional content.  As a developer the answer (unfortunately voted down) is quite useful and gives the information a developer would be interested in.

Comment: The first sentence is a good answer to the question. The rest is an explanation of why the service is better than other on the market, hence not necessary. Now the question itself doesn't seem to be on-scope here as it deals with travel reservation systems, rather than with aviation.

Comment: This a good answer but should have a clear disclaimer about your affiliation. I'd also lose the last sentence of the first paragraph